# Does not load the Vuetify installation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a project with vue and I need to work with vuetify, however when I install vuetify: "vue add vuetify", the installation does not load. In some cases, wait more than 1 hour but the installation is still unsuccessful.

I have tried this in different IDE's (Webstorm, VsCode), but it still gives the same result.

I'm new in Stack, so it doesn't allow me to place images yet :C

Comment: Welcome. We need a little more information about the problem. For example, show us what is the "result" you are talking about. Type the error or any other message it shows.

Comment: The problem is that there is no result, it only appears: installing vue-cli-plugin-vuetify ...

In all cases, the vuetify installation is very fast and options appear that you can modify during the installation. However, in my case the installation process simply stays like this

[Image Link]: https://postimg.cc/MMS049Cc

I think it may be a terminal problem (cmd)

Comment: If you are using Vue 3 you can try and install vuetify with ``vue ui``.

Comment: Thanks for the support, but, this method gives the same result as the ones already tried. And it is not installed, [Image of the result]: https://ibb.co/Qjr3QpB.

Comment: You could try the npm "have you tried turning it on and off again" - `npm cache clean --force` then try to install it again. Also, running the command line as admin is worth a shot. Don't know if it makes any difference, but you could also try it in powershell. I guess you do not have any firewall issues - have you installed something with npm successfully before this error?

Comment: I already ran the command "npm cache clean --force", but it did not give any new results, it still does not load the installation. I also try as you mentioned, run the command in administrator mode and in Powershell, but the same problem keeps happening.

Before this problem I have only installed with npm, Vue / Cli, with the command "npm install -g @ vue / cli", and Angular / Cli for other projects, but with these installations I had no problem in my projects